# OSA Script failing for JavaScript All the Sudden

Tags: applescript, automation, alfred

I'm running a simple Alfred 3 workflow as I always have but the osascript portion of it is failing all the sudden.  I've restarted my machine and of course Alfred 3.  This is the error I get in the debug panel:  **[ERROR: action.script] osascript: no such component "JavaScript"**.

I'm on OSX 10.12.5

---

If it helps, I actually submitted the question to Alfred first and they sent me here, see the original Alfred forum post:  https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/11058-osa-script-failing-for-javascript-all-the-sudden/?tab=comments#comment-57404

Comment: Does the _code_ run correctly or without error outside of Alfred?

Comment: Actually, upon further investigation...it seems that no it doesn't work in the Script Editor app on the Mac and, more disturbingly, the JXA or JavaScript option is missing completely.  I'm not sure if this happened when updating Xcode version or what.  Does anyone know how to add the JXA library back?

Comment: @user3439894 I am facing the same issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60630429/app-build-failed-in-xcode-with-continuing-in-background-failed-to-display-xcode.  Did you have any solution?

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer is my solution and it did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who may experience this issue in the future, I was able to resolve the issue by deleting the `/Users/your short name/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ScriptEditor2.plist` file and rebooting.  I can only assume this file must have somehow become corrupted and it kept the JXA option from being accessible as a script type.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** If you've ever installed the 3rd-party Script Debugger app, delete the `~/Library/Components/Script Debugger.component` folder it installs. This may immediately fix the problem (no reboot required).

This problem arose for me upon updating from Monterey to Ventura (13.2.1). Its manifestation was that my Alfred workflows using `osascript` failed to run. To diagnose that, I tried running them in Alfred's workflow debugger, and the "no such component" error appeared.

John Schulz's solution—deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ScriptEditor2.plist`—did not solve the problem for me. (I'll note that in other forums users have had success with this, but not all, so it's evidently a valid solution in some cases.)

To diagnose the problem, I listed the languages available to `osascript`:

```
$ osalang -L
asDB lns  cgxerv-h  AppleScript Debugger (AppleScript Debugger Scripting System)
ascr appl cgxervdh  AppleScript (AppleScript.)
jscr appl cgxe-v-h  AppleScript (AppleScript.)
scpt appl cgxervdh  Generic Scripting System (Transparently supports all installed OSA scripting systems.)
```

Note that `jscr` should be identified as JavaScript, not AppleScript. With that hint, more searching led to a suggestion to see if the language list changed with `sudo`. It did:

```
$ sudo osalang -L
Password:
ascr appl cgxervdh  AppleScript (AppleScript.)
jscr appl cgxe-v-h  JavaScript (JavaScript)
scpt appl cgxervdh  Generic Scripting System (Transparently supports all installed OSA scripting systems.)
```

Note that `jscr` is correctly identified as JavaScript.

With this clue, further searching led me to this Apple developer community thread: [osacompile: no such component "App… | Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649581). Multiple users there found that deleting a component folder installed by the 3rd-party [Script Debugger](https://latenightsw.com/) app solved the problem.

Specifically, delete the `~/Library/Components/Script Debugger.component` folder.

When I did that (I also completely removed Script Debugger), `osascript` correctly identified its JavaScript component without requiring `sudo` permissions:

```
$ osalang -L
ascr appl cgxervdh  AppleScript (AppleScript.)
jscr appl cgxe-v-h  JavaScript (JavaScript)
scpt appl cgxervdh  Generic Scripting System (Transparently supports all installed OSA scripting systems.)
```

My Alfred  workflows immediately worked again (no reboot required).

Note that a user in that Apple developer thread reported that launching Script Debugger after deleting the component recreated the component, but did not retrigger the bug. That user speculates an old version of the component had been left in place, with Script Debugger now replacing it with a fixed version.